# Notification from IntentService - NullPointerException while obtaining Context

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I am unable to generate the notification (in the notification area) from an `IntentService`. I get a `NullPointerException` while obtaining `NotificationManager`. The problem is with Context.

```
06-01 16:46:05.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14745): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 16:46:05.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14745):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:363)
06-01 16:46:05.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14745):     at com.Android.Main1.FileUploaderService.<init>(FileUploaderService.java:71)
```

The line of code is:

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

I have tried `getApplicationContext()`, `getBaseContext()`, but to no avail.

Could someone please let me know what is the problem here? How do I generate notifications from an IntentService?

---

Additional Info:
I also have a `Service` in my app, and notifications from there work properly. The `IntentService` is not started by an Activity; it is started by the Service.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Move your call to `getSystemService` out of the constructor and into `onCreate`.

The base `Context` in the `ContextWrapper` has not been set yet, which is causing the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - that seems to have fixed the problem. I have another issue now; I have asked the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209631/android-bad-notification-posted-couldnt-expand-remoteviews-for-statusbarnot . Could you please have a look?