# Bad notification posted - Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I am trying to post a notification with a custom view in the notification area from an `IntentService`, and getting the `Couldn't expand RemoteView` error.

Here's what I am doing in `onCreate()`:

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
icon = R.drawable.icon;
tickerText = "data upload in progress";
contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notiflayout);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.icon);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "Hello");
contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar, 100, 10, false);
whatNext = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), starterActivity.class), 0);
notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.contentView = contentView;
notification.contentIntent = whatNext;
```

I am calling `notify()` from `onHandleIntent()`, and canceling the notifications in `onDestroy()`.

I have verified that this code works in an independent app, which does not have an `IntentService`. Doing this in an `IntentService` is somehow giving trouble.

Could someone please explain what is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 16):

For me, the problem was that I was setting a specific height for the root layout, in the custom notification view xml file.

As soon as I changed:

> android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_expanded"

to

> android:layout_height="match_parent"

in the root layout of notification view, the problem was solved.

Also take a look at [this example](https://www.swipetips.com/android-custom-notification-tutorial/) to see a simple example of using custom layout for notifications.

Comment: In android 5.0+,i failed to fix this ```Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification```error until i set the custom view root's height to android:layout_height="64dp"...but i do not meet this error below 5.0,It's weird.

Answer (score 13):

for unknown reason you are not allowed to reference dimention in the root view of the custom remote view! so you have to hard code it like `android:layout_height="64dp"` but if you used `android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_height_that_64"` it will give you `Bad notification posted - Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification` . i hope this will help :)

Comment: U saved my day...thanks a ton....but I don't know what is the reason behind...why doesn't it take dimen for custom view?

Answer (score 11):

In my case the exception was caused by a regular `View` in my custom notification layout. Basically, it's because you're allowed to use only certain widgets like TextView, ImageView and so on.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, i was able to fix this error by reducing the icon size i was providing into  `.setSmallIcon();`

Comment: this was also my issue adjusting to android recommended sizes fixed this for me > https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html#size11

Answer (score 7):

For me the problem was having a `View` item in the custom layout set for the custom notification. Removing the `View` item from the layout solved the problem of the Bad Notification Posted.

Here's a [list of layout items](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) which can be used, if you want to create a custom notification using `RemoteView`.

Neither cleaning project nor setting the `layout_height` as `match_parent` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. In my case:

reason -> I used for the builder.setAction(R.drawable.icon,...) function a vectordrawable and I tried also to enable them from support lib but nothing worked. In recent Android systems I do not see action icons, in the others it gives this error.

solution -> I did not find nothing, the only workaround for me is to avoid .xml files for drawables and to use the .png files in all directories hdpi mdpi ldpi..

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error, but the problem for me was the constrain layout. I changed it to `Relative Layout` to fix the the problem.

Answer (score 3):

i see the is alot of trouble related to this topic, in my case this problem was caused by using

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

i used that on my `ImageButton` and each time my app crashed but when i removed it, everything was fine, i guess the problem is you should not use any custom `View` type or any theme attributes on your views, i hope this will help another stuck with this problem

Comment: I was facing the same problem and I was using attributes for android:background so removing it solved my case

Answer (score 1):

@Nikolai's answer was helpful for me, indeed it was the problem.
I had the same issue. There are specific controls that can be used in the notification. I had a View in my layout for notification as below.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.04"/>
```

This was causing the crash. 
Following Layouts and controls are supported:
[image]

As per this [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#CreatingLayout).

I removed it and it worked fine. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using Vector drawables. On pre-Lollipop devices setting an icon through `NotificationCompat.Builder` methods, like `setSmallIcon`, will cause this crash. You'll get same crash if using Vector drawables in your  custom view.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue in showing custom layout in notification and what i found is:

I was using **ConstraintsLayout** as a root layout of my custom notification, this is the mistake i was committing. As there are some limitations with constrain layout to be used in android.

Finally i changed my root layout to **RelativeLayout** and my notification showing perfectly. I have attached my view in below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was an inconsistency between the call

```
setShowActionsInCompactView(0)
```

And the `.addAction` calls...The number of actions was different, hence the error

Answer (score 0):

Don't use XML **vector** drawables for older android versions. It will crash the app. Use PNGs

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was on `NotificationCompat.Builder.addAction` the icon i set for action not compatible with all devices . I use **Andriod Studio -> File -> New -> Image Asset** to generate the icon then it fine .

Answer (score 0):

In my case
In addAction icon(1st arg) were the problem.
i changed it to png, it worked.
then tried it with 0, that worked too.