# Bad notification posted from package Couldn't expand RemoteViews

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a problem. Some times my service is forcefully closed with this logcat:

```
03-26 20:44:44.849: E/AndroidRuntime(12080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 20:44:44.849: E/AndroidRuntime(12080): android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package by.flipdev.vkspy: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=by.flipdev.vkspy id=1 tag=null score=0 notn=Notification(pri=0 contentView=by.flipdev.vkspy/0x1090071 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x2 kind=[null]))
03-26 20:44:44.849: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
03-26 20:44:44.849: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 20:44:44.849: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 20:44:44.849: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
03-26 20:44:44.849: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 20:44:44.849: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 20:44:44.849: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-26 20:44:44.849: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
03-26 20:44:44.849: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my code to add add notifications:

```
protected void addNotification(final Bitmap Avatar,
        final int small_Image_ID, final int notify_id, final String text,
        final String title, final Boolean ongoing, final Boolean ticker,
        final String tickerText, final Boolean autoCancel,
        final String notificationCategory, final int notificationValue) {

    try {

        final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(
                getApplicationContext(), CheckerActivity.class);

        notificationIntent
                .putExtra(notificationCategory, notificationValue);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), notify_id, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        if (Ticker) {
            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(small_Image_ID)
                    .setOngoing(ongoing)                    
                    .setLargeIcon(Avatar).setTicker(tickerText)                     
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setAutoCancel(AutoCancel).setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text); // Текст уведомления
        } else {
            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(small_Image_ID)
                    .setLargeIcon(avatar)                       
                    .setOngoing(ongoing)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setAutoCancel(AutoCancel).setContentTitle(title) 
                    .setContentText(text); // Текст уведомления
        }

        final Notification n = builder.getNotification();

        nm.notify(notify_id, n);

    } catch (final Exception e) {
                    // TODO: add exception handling code
    }
}
```

Why is my service killed?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but maybe related to your avatar bitmap? Is it ever null?

Comment: Can you make a check in your code if Avatar image is not null?
<br>For small_Image_ID where do you assign the value ?
<br>If the notification manager can't find a ressource it trigger that kind of message: Bad notification posted XXXX.
<br>So first thing to check is that all value does exist.
<br>Thx

Comment: i'd say either avatar is null or small_Image_ID does not refer to a drawable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android - Bad notification posted - Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209631/android-bad-notification-posted-couldnt-expand-remoteviews-for-statusbarno)

Comment: seems like the avatar is not null: contentView=by.flipdev.vkspy/0x1090071

Comment: I think getApplicationContext() is the problem here it may be null.

Comment: please post your service implementation

Comment: @user2212515, did you figure out the solution. I am still getting this exception , nothing worked for me for 4.4.2 .

Answer (score 6):

I noticed this happening on **3.0** emulators, when I set the Large Icon.

So, since the Large Icon is only used by **4.0+** devices, I solved this issue by checking if the Build version is > 13. If so (and only if so), I set the Large icon.

The problem has gone.

Comment: Very helpful! Indeed, `builder.setLargeIcon()` crashes on API level 12 (at least the emulator). (I've never been able to test on the level 13-14 emulators since they take most of an hour to start up, then crash before they're ready to do anything.) I previously found that `builder.setNumber()` also crashes on the API level 12 emulator.

Comment: Well, nothing to worry about anymore. According to the [Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) 3.x devices are now **less than the 0.1%** of the global market, so they won't even be anymore listed. Anyway, this is why I do set it only on devices > 13 (`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13){...}`).

Comment: @Rotwang, I am getting this exception in 4.4.2 version. Not able to trace it.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is a result of missing or null resources. 
Looking at your code, I infer that, possible error seems to be on Ticker *(always false)* and `setLargeIcon(avatar)`*( avatar is always null)*.

Could you post all your service implementations?

P.S. Please try to respect java's naming convention; Ticker,Avatar,AutoCancel and other objects should start with lower case.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in my case, I was getting this exact same error because I referred to a style definition for a TextView in my custom notification layout that had an entry for an onClick target method. Specifically:

```
<item name="android:onClick">onClick</item>
```

Once I removed that line, the problem went away.  An oversight on my part, but a good reminder not to blindly reuse styles.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from recommended Layouts and Widgets by Google
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews

Check you `layout.xml` file and if you using `android:tint` property remove it.
Because `RemoteViews` do not accept layout.xml with `android:tint`