# Bad notification posted from package - Is it compulsary to hardcode values in the custom layout used for building notifications?

Tags: android, notifications

I am getting the following crash from Crashlytics. Not able to reproduce locally.

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.abc: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.abc id=71404926 tag=null score=20 notn=Notification(pri=2 contentView=com.eterno/0x7f04016c vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 kind=[null]) tickerText=पीएम मोदी की पाकिस्तानी बहन राखी बांधने दिल्ली पहुंची contactCharSeq=null when=1502090973664 threadId=0)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Since it is not happening on every device and the stack trace doesn't give much info, I have come up with the following root cause for this crash.

1. The notification in my app is prepared with a custom layout. The layout references a dimension as `@dimen/some_value` for setting the margin of the image logo.
2. The notification is posted to the `NotificationManager` via `notify()` function.
3. Meanwhile, app gets updated and `@dimen/some_value` gets some other resource id. (Verified this thing. Two different apks will have different resource id for the same resource).
4. When the system tries to draw the notification on the StatusBarNotification, it does not find the resource id and it crashes.

So, the idea is to remove the referenced variable and replace it with hardcoded string.

i.e  Replace

```
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/notification_text_margin_left"
```

with

```
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
```

I did not find any official document telling me to do this, but found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41363437/1237141). Just wanted to know that can there be any other reason for this crash? Also, is the fix correct for the crash?

P.S. This crash is happening across all handsets and all OS versions.

Comment: add some code so we can help you

Comment: for inflating the `remoteviews` android system is using `getDimensionPixelOffset` function